Disposing an IAsyncEnumerator does not cancel the underlying IAsyncEnumerable's cancellation token
It appears that disposing a generated IAsyncEnumerable's IAsyncEnumerator does not trigger the cancellation token of the underlying IAsyncEnumerable.
Specifically, this unit test fails its only assertion:
[Test]
public async Task test()
{
    await foreach (var value in TestData())
        break;
}

private static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> TestData([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    try
    {
        yield return 1;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        yield return 2;
    }
    finally
    {
        Assert.That(ct.IsCancellationRequested, Is.True);
    }
}

I'm extremely surprised by this behaviour. Is there any standard approach to have TestData's CancellationToken cancelled in this scenario?
I could implement a custom operator, but that feels extremely clunky, so I'm hoping that there's some better way of doing this.
[Test]
public async Task this_test_passes()
{
    await foreach (var value in CancelWhenUnsubscribed(TestData()))
        break;
}

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> CancelWhenUnsubscribed<T>(IAsyncEnumerable<T> source, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    using var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(ct);
    await using var en = source.GetAsyncEnumerator(cts.Token);
    using var _ = Disposable.Create(() => cts.Cancel());
    while (await en.MoveNextAsync())
        yield return en.Current;
}


For context why I'm trying to do this: I am using System.Interactive.Async to merge a few IAsyncEnumerable sequences.
Its implementation works in a way that when the merged sequence is disposed, it first waits for any in-flight MoveNext tasks to complete, and only then disposes and terminates the merged sequence.
In my specific case, that means I need to cancel the underlying IAsyncEnumerables when the merged one is terminated, otherwise I'll run into quasi-deadlocks. As a simple example, this test here gets stuck:
[Test]
public async Task this_test_gets_stuck()
{
    await foreach (var value in AsyncEnumerableEx.Merge([TestData(), TestData()]))
        break;
}

private static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> TestData([EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    yield return 1;
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromHours(100), ct);
    yield return 2;
}


No longer reading a sequence: is not cancellation. These are different concepts, and IMO it is functioning correctly. Moreover, since the token is passed in externally via WithCancellation, the iterator literally cannot trigger cancellation: you need the CTS for that, not just the CT. You already have finally - you can perhaps create your own "linked" CTS which you additionally trigger from finally?

No cancellation token is passed to TestData so why the surprise? CancellationToken ct = default means that ct has its default value, None. Cancellation is triggered by a CancellationTokenSource, not by the CancellationToken itself. The CancellationToken is used to observe the cancellation only

@MarcGravell Good point. Since TestData is compiler-rewritten, I suppose in a whacky world it may have been possible to rewrite it in a way such that the cancellationToken referenced from within the function would be replaced with a token that is linked to the original arg, but also disposed on exit. But admittedly if thinking about the exact semantics, that would probably be more surprising / make the differentiation between exiting &cancelling impossible (though I'm not sure I can think of many sensible real world use cases when anyone would prefer the token not to be cancelled on exit)

@Bogey ultimately, cancellation exists to allow for cancellation during async operations; simply ceasing iteration happens outside of the async flow, and is already well supported via finally

I don't get why you are surprised. The TestData iterator doesn't own the CancellationToken, so it's not its responsibility to cancel it, even if it could. Actually it can't cancel it, for reasons discussed in this question:

Why CancellationToken is separate from CancellationTokenSource?

If you invoke the TestData without passing a CancellationToken, and without using the WithCancellation extension method, the ct.CanBeCanceled will be false. In which case it would be absurd to expect the automatic cancellation of a token that cannot be canceled.

[1/2] Let's put it this way, it's surprising to me on an intuitive level. If you show e.g. my last example (merge) to a random selection of devs, I'm not sure how many would spot the issue / that the call would hang (I admittedly didn't). But you're right in the sense that if thinking about how this exactly translates to compiled generated code & works in terms of the involved IAsyncEnumerators, it's somewhat more understandable.

[2/2] My very personal opinion is that this behaviour is still a bit nasty as at least personally, I have absolutely no use cases where I wouldn't want to cancel on exit (and would imagine that is probably the more desirable behaviour in almost all cases), so it "feels" a bit like something to which a clear, concise and easy out of the box solution should arguably exist - but it is what it is of course

@Bogey we can only guess. My personal guess is that almost 100% of the random selection of devs who are familiar with the CancellationToken, would expect it to not be automatically canceled. Honestly it looks more like a personal misconception. Which is OK. Everyone has a few of them, myself included.
